# Equivalent C# code for the VB counterpart

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I was converting some VB code to C#. I have these 2 statements with me currently written in `VB`

```
Dim LineSeparator As Char = Convert.ToChar(10)
        Dim DataSeparator As Char = Convert.ToChar(";")
```

I checked the value in `Watch` Window and could see something like this

```
Name            Value   Type        

LineSeparator   ""c     Char

DataSeparator   ";"c    Char
```

I wrote similar `C#` statements

```
char LineSeparator = Convert.ToChar(10);
char DataSeparator = Convert.ToChar(";");
```

but the watch shows a different result. Something Like this

```
LineSeparator   10 '\n' char


DataSeparator   59 ';'  char
```

What Wrong I am doing here? Do i need to put Single Quotes around the parameters?

Comment: No the results are correct, it is only a different way to show the values between C# and VB.NET

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @Steve Perfect ! It is printing the ASCII code in the watch window that confused me :)

Comment: Fun fact - if you use the the pinned Datatip (hover over variable-click the pin icon) in VS2010 thru VS2013, for Datatip will show `"\n"c` for your `LineSeparator` variable in VB.  In VS2015, it shows as `vbLf`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the results are correct, it is only a difference in the way used by the debug window to show certain constant values between C# and VB.NET

The character with code 10 is the LineFeed character (a non printable one) and the debugger in VB don't show anything between the double quotes (but the character is there). In the C# debugger these non printable characters are represented by the escape prefix (\) follwed by one letter defined for some of them.

For the semicolon instead, the problem is that VB.NET use the same quoting both for a single character and for strings. Thus they added the letter "c" to show that this is a char value and not a string. Instead C# uses the single quote around character constants